# How to apply custom attribute value on cost

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am new to Magento. I am trying to achieve a simple way to apply custom margin at cost and then get its sale price. I want to put only cost then some function to calculate 20% VAT (TAX) and custom attributes margin which suppose I set 15%.

Example:

I have three fields when adding or editing product :

```
Cost = 100 
Price = 0 
margin_percentage: 15 (means 15%)
```

After user add 100 and margin percentage 15, system first calculate 20% VAT then on resulting amount add 15% margin so I get this case

cost + vat + margin = 138
**after saving**

```
Cost = 100 
Price = 138 
margin_percentage: 15
```

I have write a module and tried to achieve this using Event Observer - **catalog_product_save_before** and **catalog_product_save_after** 
here is a function. If this code works I may apply formula's, but I try to update db tables nothing happened. I don't know what is going wrong. 
I am trying to update this table `catalog_product_flat_1`

```
class SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{
/**
 * Magento passes a Varien_Event_Observer object as
 * the first parameter of dispatched events.
 */
public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $cost = $product->getCost();

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $_product->setPrice($cost); // or an other price field
    $_product->save();

    Mage::log(
        "cost {$cost} Price {$price} ",
        null, 
        'product-updates.log'
    );
}
```

}

I follow this tutorial for making this module http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/ ... now what is wrong with the above code? Also give me execution time out error. My server current execution time is 300000

Hope someone guide me to a right direction

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write the price in the Magento catalog/price mobel object?

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$_product->setPrice($cost); // or an other price field
$_product->save();
```

instead of:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$connection->beginTransaction();
$fields = array();
$fields['price'] = $cost;
$where = $connection->quoteInto('entity_id =?', $id);
$connection->update('catalog_product_flat_1', $fields, $where);
$connection->commit();
```

Comment: `  public function productUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
  $cost = $product->getCost();
        $price = $product->getprice();
  $id = $product->getEntityId();
  
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $_product->setPrice($cost); // or an other price field
        $_product->save();

    }`  thanks Roy.. i test this but price not updated still empty field.. i also disable cache

Comment: See this [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/znEip1Uy) which have some logging. Could you try to see what the logging shows you?

Comment: i try but ...Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home3/rahman12/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Attribute.php on line 255

Comment: How many products are you trying to update? And what does your log file saids?

Comment: so there is nothing in var/log/product-updates.log ?

Comment: log file is there.. but not updated one.. showing old data.. im transfer my module to my second server..which is dedicated.. after that  i tell u.. thanks for your king help.. back in 15 min

Comment: i have only 64 products.. execuation time is 300000.. nothing happening.. no log file generated this new server ..... now have error
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved .. one thing i want to share in above code. problem in above code i reload model 2 time. after removing this model

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
```

now problem solved

Thanks all

Best Regards